# How did the solution guide find this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: This is the problem]

[image: This is the problem]

I'm not sure how they found this matrix, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: find which matrix? They are all given...

Answer (score 1):

The definition of $v_1,v_2$ by the matrix product can be written
$$\begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2\end{bmatrix} = Q\cdot R=\begin{bmatrix} b_1 & b_2\end{bmatrix}\cdot R.$$
In particular, $v_1$ is obtained as a linear combination of $b_1,b_2$, with the coefficient given by the first column of $R$. Similarly, $v_2$ is obtained by taking a linear combination of $b_1,b_2$ with the coefficients given by the second column. So the columns of $R$ are the coordinates of $v_1$ and $v_2$ in the basis $\mathcal{B}=\{b_1,b_2\}$, which means $R$ is the change of basis matrix $\mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{B}$.